# transform queryset to dict of dicts django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-queryset

i am trying to make a dict of dicts with data and pass it to template.

models.py

```
 class Lesson(models.Model):
 ...

 class Files(models.Model):
 ...

 class Section(models.Model):
   file = models.ManyToManyField(Files)
   lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson)
```

views.py

```
def LessonView(request):
    the_data={}
    all_lessons= Lesson.objects.all()
    for lesson in all_lessons:
        the_data[lesson]=lesson.section_set.all()
        for section in the_data[lesson]:
            the_data[lesson][section]=section.file.all() <---error
    Context={
        'the_data':the_data,
        }
return render(request, 'TMS/lessons.html', Context)
```

i get an  error:

```
 Exception Value:   

 'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment
```

i am new to django and programming so take it easy.is this the right way to pass the data so i can show a list of files for each section for each lesson,in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert to a dict of dicts to pass to the template. You can iterate through the queryset directly, and for each one you can get the related sections and files:

```
{% for lesson in all_lessons %}
    {{ lesson.name }}
    {% for section in lesson.section_set.all %}
        {{ section.name }}
        {% for file in section.file.all %}
            {{ file.name }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that this (just like your original approach) is very expensive in terms of database queries: you should investigate using [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) in the view to cut down on those.